# X over sshd, XWindow hanging, ps -ef causes ssh connection to stall

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm, ubuntu-16.04, xserver

I have a development machine, which runs on Amazon EC2 and which is accessed primarily from a Windows computer using MobaXTerm. The primary use is to start and work with Jetbrains PHPStorm, a Java based IDE.

I regularly experience the IDE locking up. When this happens a range of strange things happen:

A Other ssh connections on command line within MobaXterm to the same machine work until I type in "ps -ef" and the line with PHPStorm appears:

```
jochen@devserver:~/projects/infoodle$ ps -ef
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
root         1     0  0 00:52 ?        00:00:03 /sbin/init
root         2     0  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [kthreadd]
root         3     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/0]
root         5     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0H]
root         7     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_sched]
root         8     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [rcu_bh]
root         9     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [migration/0]
root        10     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/0]
root        11     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/1]
root        12     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [migration/1]
root        13     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/1]
root        15     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:0H]
root        16     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/2]
root        17     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [migration/2]
root        18     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/2]
root        20     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:0H]
root        21     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [watchdog/3]
root        22     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [migration/3]
root        23     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [ksoftirqd/3]
root        25     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:0H]
root        26     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [kdevtmpfs]
root        27     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [netns]
root        28     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [perf]
root        29     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [xenwatch]
root        30     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [xenbus]
root        31     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:1]
root        32     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [khungtaskd]
root        33     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [writeback]
root        34     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [ksmd]
root        35     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [khugepaged]
root        36     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [crypto]
root        37     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [kintegrityd]
root        38     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root        39     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [kblockd]
root        41     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [ata_sff]
root        42     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [md]
root        43     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [devfreq_wq]
root        48     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [kswapd0]
root        49     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [vmstat]
root        50     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [fsnotify_mark]
root        51     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [ecryptfs-kthrea]
root        67     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [kthrotld]
root        68     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [acpi_thermal_pm]
root        69     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root        70     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root        71     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root        72     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root        73     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root        74     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root        75     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root        76     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root        77     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_0]
root        78     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_0]
root        79     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_eh_1]
root        80     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [scsi_tmf_1]
root        82     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root        87     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [ipv6_addrconf]
root       100     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root       101     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [deferwq]
root       102     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [charger_manager]
root       136     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root       137     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root       138     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root       139     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root       140     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root       141     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root       142     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root       143     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root       146     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [kpsmoused]
root       256     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [raid5wq]
root       282     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [bioset]
root       308     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [jbd2/xvda1-8]
root       309     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [ext4-rsv-conver]
root       354     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:1H]
root       355     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:1H]
root       368     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:1H]
root       395     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-journald
root       402     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [iscsi_eh]
root       404     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [kauditd]
root       407     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [ib_addr]
root       417     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [ib_mcast]
root       418     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [ib_nl_sa_wq]
root       420     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [ib_cm]
root       423     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [iw_cm_wq]
root       424     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [rdma_cm]
root       443     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/lvmetad -f
root       461     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:1H]
root       468     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
root       683     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [loop0]
root       695     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [loop1]
root       713     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [loop2]
root       724     2  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 [loop3]
root       930     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/dhclient -1 -v -pf /run/dhclient.ens3.pid -lf /var/lib/dhcp/dhclient.ens3.leases -I -df /var/
root      1235     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/iscsid
root      1236     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/iscsid
root      1238     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/accountsservice/accounts-daemon
root      1240     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
root      1242     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.0/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
root      1244     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/snapd/snapd
root      1246     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.1/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
root      1250     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/acpid
root      1270     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:09 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd://
root      1275     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/sshd -D
syslog    1282     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/rsyslogd -n
daemon    1285     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/atd -f
root      1298     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: master process (/etc/php/7.2/fpm/php-fpm.conf)
message+  1300     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-activation
root      1319     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd-logind
root      1322     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/lxcfs /var/lib/lxcfs/
mysql     1330     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:07 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root      1353     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /sbin/mdadm --monitor --pid-file /run/mdadm/monitor.pid --daemonise --scan --syslog
root      1355     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/policykit-1/polkitd --no-debug
www-data  1402  1298  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  1403  1298  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  1413  1246  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
www-data  1414  1246  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 php-fpm: pool www
root      1456  1270  0 00:52 ?        00:00:06 containerd -l unix:///var/run/docker/libcontainerd/docker-containerd.sock --metrics-interval=0 --st
root      1487     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/irqbalance --pid=/var/run/irqbalance.pid
ntp       1527     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/ntpd -p /var/run/ntpd.pid -g -u 114:121
root      1537     1  0 00:52 ttyS0    00:00:00 /sbin/agetty --keep-baud 115200 38400 9600 ttyS0 vt220
root      1538     1  0 00:52 tty1     00:00:00 /sbin/agetty --noclear tty1 linux
root      1614     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
jochen    1644  1614  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
jochen    1646  1614  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
jochen    1647  1614  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
jochen    1648  1614  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root      1818     1  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/postfix/sbin/master
postfix   1820  1818  0 00:52 ?        00:00:00 qmgr -l -t unix -u
jochen    2530     1  0 01:02 ?        00:00:00 /lib/systemd/systemd --user
jochen    2532  2530  0 01:02 ?        00:00:00 (sd-pam)
root      3402  1275  0 01:08 ?        00:00:00 sshd: jochen [priv]
jochen    3444  3402  0 01:08 ?        00:00:00 sshd: jochen@notty
jochen    3445  3444  0 01:08 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
root      3616     2  0 01:09 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/2:0]
jochen    3632  1614  0 01:09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
jochen    3637  1614  0 01:09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
jochen    3638  1614  0 01:09 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
root      4224     2  0 01:39 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/1:1]
root      4242     2  0 01:52 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/0:0]
root      4396     2  0 02:09 ?        00:00:00 [kworker/3:2]
root      4468  1275  0 02:20 ?        00:00:00 sshd: jochen [priv]
root      4485  1275  0 02:20 ?        00:00:00 sshd: jochen [priv]
jochen    4545  4468  1 02:20 ?        00:00:42 sshd: jochen@pts/0
jochen    4575  4485  0 02:20 ?        00:00:00 sshd: jochen@notty
jochen    4576  4575  0 02:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/lib/openssh/sftp-server
jochen    4577  4545  0 02:20 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh ./bin//jetbrains-toolbox
jochen    4582     1  0 02:20 ?        00:00:01 /home/jochen/jetbrains-toolbox-1.6.2914/jetbrains-toolbox
jochen    4596  4577  0 02:20 pts/0    00:00:08 share/jetbrains-toolbox/jetbrains-toolbox --disable-gpu --single-process --no-sandbox
jochen    4615     1  0 02:20 pts/0    00:00:00 dbus-launch --autolaunch e8a9093133ed49fb8f2465d03bf5750c --binary-syntax --close-stderr
jochen    4616     1  0 02:20 ?        00:00:00 /usr/bin/dbus-daemon --fork --print-pid 5 --print-address 7 --session
jochen    4669  4596  0 02:20 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/sh /home/jochen/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/PhpStorm/ch-0/181.3870.19/bin/phpstorm.sh
```

B I cannot open new ssh connections to the development machine  in MobaXterm.

C I can dial into other servers with MobaXterm, but from these other servers cannot ssh into the development machine either. The -vvv log is

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /root/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "devserver.automatem.co.nz" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to devserver.automatem.co.nz [13.210.31.246] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file id_rsa-jochen type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file id_rsa-jochen-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to devserver.automatem.co.nz:22 as 'jochen'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from devserver.automatem.co.nz
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:JcPPe2SQPfwoONjws7l2sYwkeeJasztPTww67lqI/Ik
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from devserver.automatem.co.nz
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/root/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /root/.ssh/known_hosts:11
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 13.210.31.246
debug1: Host 'devserver.automatem.co.nz' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:10
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: jochen-windows (0x561cca47a250), agent
debug2: key: id_rsa-jochen ((nil)), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: jochen-windows
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 60
debug1: Server accepts key: pkalg rsa-sha2-512 blen 277
debug2: input_userauth_pk_ok: fp SHA256:JiGG4lMVcyq8MOzTMskuOZ7ww6maX6wjpMVjW76t9+Q
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:JiGG4lMVcyq8MOzTMskuOZ7ww6maX6wjpMVjW76t9+Q
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 52
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to devserver.automatem.co.nz ([13.210.31.246]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0
debug2: channel 0: send open
debug3: send packet: type 90
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug3: send packet: type 80
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug3: receive packet: type 80
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
debug3: receive packet: type 91
debug2: callback start
debug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x10
debug2: client_session2_setup: id 0
debug2: channel 0: request pty-req confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug1: Sending environment.
debug3: Ignored env XDG_SESSION_ID
debug3: Ignored env TERM
debug3: Ignored env SHELL
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CLIENT
debug3: Ignored env SSH_TTY
debug3: Ignored env USER
debug3: Ignored env LS_COLORS
debug3: Ignored env SSH_AUTH_SOCK
debug3: Ignored env MAIL
debug3: Ignored env PATH
debug3: Ignored env PWD
debug3: Ignored env EDITOR
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug2: channel 0: request env confirm 0
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug3: Ignored env SHLVL
debug3: Ignored env HOME
debug3: Ignored env LOGNAME
debug3: Ignored env SSH_CONNECTION
debug3: Ignored env LESSOPEN
debug3: Ignored env XDG_RUNTIME_DIR
debug3: Ignored env DISPLAY
debug3: Ignored env LESSCLOSE
debug3: Ignored env _
debug2: channel 0: request shell confirm 1
debug3: send packet: type 98
debug2: callback done
debug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768
```

D Restarting the EC2 instance does not seem to work anymore

E Stopping the instance takes a very long time, which from my experience  indicates a lack of RAM. I have however tried this with 16GB and 32GB machines and have added 2GB of swap space as well. This is much bigger than my other desktop development machine, where PhpStorm never freezes up.

The operating system is Ubuntu 16.04, which is fully up to date.

From the Amazon control panel, I have checked all EC2 metrics and the only ones that have any measurements are Network in and Out:

[image]

I have also checked the metrics on the attached, single EBS disk of 50GB, which is shown here:

[image]

The highest metric is 66.6KBytes VolumeWriteBytes, which is well below the stated performance of 150 IOPS/ 2400Kb/s for a 50GB volume

PhPStrom log file here: https://gist.github.com/jochendaum/e41019f9ec76f82bea975f93e7531f3a

Comment: _I regularly experience the IDE locking up_ - could you please explicitly describe that? E.g. IDE UI just freezes bit the rest of OS UI is operative.You might want to share here the idea.log (Help > Show log in...) file for us to inspect.

Comment: Hi, I'm using this computer for about 4 sessions of 3h each per week and it locks up i about 75% of the sessions. Lock up: Nothing works, nothing moves, no menus, characters entered, no element works by mouse

Comment: have added php log file. I have also noticed that when the machine is running for about 8 hours without anything connected, I am not able to connect to it anymore. I am trying to find out when this happens by trying out ssh monitoring

Comment: 1) Check if you have any /home/jochen/java_error_in_PHPSTORM_%p.log files on that server. 2) check if you have "thread dump ***" folders in your log folder. If you do - please archive & upload somewhere them

Comment: Yes I have threaddumps https://s3-ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/jdshare/threadDump.tar.gz I have also monitored ssh connectivity with anturis.com and it failed after 3 hours of the instance being stopped/started. As this is a R4 instance, I am wondering if there are issues with Networking, even though enhanced networking is not enabled and an Elastic Networking Interface is not configured, nor is this enabled at instance level.